# Ionic - item does two way data binding in the nav bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an icon in the nav bar should display or not according to position true / false toggle . Testing in view works perfectly but the result does not work in the nav bar . Both pages use the same controller . Translator English

**index.html - nav-bar**

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable" ng-controller="DashCtrl">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <i class="icon ion-eye ng-show="vaovivo.valor"></i>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-nav-bar
```

**Account.html - toggle**

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="vaovivo.valor" ng-checked="vaovivo.valor">
  Modo ao Vivo
</ion-toggle>
```

**Controllers.js**

angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {    
  $scope.vaovivo = {'valor':false}
})
```

**app.js**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
```

**UPDATE:**
**index.html - nav-bar**

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable" ng-controller="DashCtrl">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <i class="icon ion-eye" ng-show="vaovivo.valor"></i>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-nav-bar>
```

Comment: Can you show me routes file?

Answer (score 0):

The logic looks sound but there is one thing that might prevent the ng-show to work in the nav-bar. You are not closing the ion-nav-bar properly and might be the issue.

Firstly, close of the ng-class properly like by adding a closing quote

```
<i class="icon ion-eye" ng-show="vaovivo.valor"></i>
```

Secondly close the ion-nav-bar properly.

```
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Comment: Sorry for the basic mistake was to transcribe the code . The problem continues.